# Android Multithreading

Tags: android, multithreading, opencv, bitmap

I have a piece of code that is removing bitmap background, at first the code was taking about `40s>` to remove each bitmap background but I optimized to about `12s`on a hauwei y320 -u30 with quadcore 1.3ghz each and `6s` on Galaxy s3 Quadcore although this is pretty good compared to the first product it is not good enough I want it start ranging in about `2s` to `3s` for the huawei due to the fact that the base user will probably have a low end device, I am using an async task with fixed `fixedthreadpool` of `2` and thread priority of `Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND +
                    Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_MORE_FAVORABLE)` but I was wondering, I know multi threading is the ability of running multiple tasks per single time frame but isnt there a way I can run `2 or 3` threads on one task, for example in my case run the threads on my background removal code, am sure this can yield better performance due to the fact that at the time am running this code there is no other thread within my app that is also running, I have all resources per run time of my code, I looked up online but I cannot find anything related to that, below is the my code:

```
public class ImageBackgrndRemover extends AppCompatActivity {



private BaseLoaderCallback  mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch (status) {
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
            {
                Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");

                //instantia


                if(!alreadyRun) {

                    BackgroundRemover remover = null;
                    if(remover == null)
                    {
                        remover = new BackgroundRemover();
                        remover.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.DUAL_THREAD_EXECUTOR);

                    }


                }

            } break;
            default:
            {
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
            } break;
        }
    }
};

private LoadingAnimation add;
ImageView iv;
Scalar color;
Mat dst;
private boolean alreadyRun;
public static final String TAG = "Grabcut demo";


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_backgrnd_remover);
    iv = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imagePreview);



}

private int calculatePercentage(int percentage, int target)
{
    int k = (int)(target*(percentage/100.0f));
    return k;

}
private Bitmap backGrndErase()
{

    color = new Scalar(255, 0, 0, 255);
    dst = new Mat();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.myshirt);
    Log.d(TAG, "bitmap: " + bitmap.getWidth() + "x" + bitmap.getHeight());


    bitmap = ResizeImage.getResizedBitmap(bitmap, calculatePercentage(40, bitmap.getWidth()), calculatePercentage(40, bitmap.getHeight()));

    // Bitmap bitmap2 = ImageCornerMoulder.getRoundedCornerBitmap(bmp, calculatePercentage(5, bmp.getHeight()));


    bitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    Log.d(TAG, "bitmap 8888: " + bitmap.getWidth() + "x" + bitmap.getHeight());


    //GrabCut part
    Mat img = new Mat();
    Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, img);
    Log.d(TAG, "img: " + img);

    int r = img.rows();
    int c = img.cols();

    Point p1 = new Point(c/10, r/10);
    Point p2 = new Point(c-c/10, r-r/10);

    int border = 20;
    int border2 = border + border;
    Rect rect2 = new Rect(border,border,img.cols()-border2,img.rows()-border2);


    Rect rect = new Rect(p1,p2);

    Log.d(TAG, "rect: " + rect);

    Mat mask = new Mat();
    debugger(""+mask.type());
    mask.setTo(new Scalar(125));
    Mat fgdModel = new Mat();
    fgdModel.setTo(new Scalar(255, 255, 255));
    Mat bgdModel = new Mat();
    bgdModel.setTo(new Scalar(255, 255, 255));

    Mat imgC3 = new Mat();
    Imgproc.cvtColor(img, imgC3, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2RGB);
    Log.d(TAG, "imgC3: " + imgC3);

    Log.d(TAG, "Grabcut begins");
    Imgproc.grabCut(imgC3, mask, rect2, bgdModel, fgdModel, 2, Imgproc.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT);

    Mat source = new Mat(1, 1, CvType.CV_8U, new Scalar(3.0));


    Core.compare(mask, source, mask, Core.CMP_EQ);
    Mat foreground = new Mat(img.size(), CvType.CV_8UC3, new Scalar(255, 255, 255));
    img.copyTo(foreground, mask);
    Imgproc.rectangle(img, p1, p2, color);

    Mat background = new Mat();
    try {
        background = Utils.loadResource(getApplicationContext(),
                R.drawable.blackcolor );
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Mat tmp = new Mat();
    Imgproc.resize(background, tmp, img.size());

    background = tmp;

    Mat tempMask = new Mat(foreground.size(), CvType.CV_8UC1, new Scalar(255, 255, 255));
    Imgproc.cvtColor(foreground, tempMask, 6/* COLOR_BGR2GRAY */);
    //Imgproc.threshold(tempMask, tempMask, 254, 255, 1 /* THRESH_BINARY_INV */);

    Mat vals = new Mat(1, 1, CvType.CV_8UC3, new Scalar(0.0));
    dst = new Mat();
    background.setTo(vals, tempMask);
    Imgproc.resize(foreground, tmp, mask.size());
    foreground = tmp;
    Core.add(background, foreground, dst, tempMask);
    Log.d(TAG, "Convert to Bitmap");


    //removing blackbaground started
    /***
    Mat tmp2 = new Mat();
    Mat alpha = new Mat();
    Imgproc.cvtColor(dst, tmp2, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    Imgproc.threshold(tmp2, alpha, 100, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);


    List<Mat> rgb = new ArrayList<Mat>(3);
    Core.split(dst, rgb);


    List<Mat> rgba = new ArrayList<Mat>(4);
    rgba.add(rgb.get(0));
    rgba.add(rgb.get(1));
    rgba.add(rgb.get(2));
    rgba.add(alpha);
    Core.merge(rgba, dst);
     Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(dst.width(), dst.height(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
     Utils.matToBitmap(dst, output);
     ***/
    //removing back ended


   Utils.matToBitmap(dst, bitmap);



    //release MAT part
    img.release();
    imgC3.release();
    mask.release();
    fgdModel.release();
    bgdModel.release();
    alreadyRun = true;
    return  bitmap;

}

private void showLoadingIndicator()
{

    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    add = LoadingAnimation.newInstance("b");
    add.show(fm, "");
    add.setCancelable(false);

}

private void dismissLoadingIndicator()
{
    try {
        add.dismiss();
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
private class BackgroundRemover extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>
{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        showLoadingIndicator();
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... voids) {


        Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND +
                Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_MORE_FAVORABLE);

        try{


            return backGrndErase();

        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println("Failed to remove background");
        }

        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {


      //  iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blackcolor);
        iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        dismissLoadingIndicator();
    }
}


@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Internal OpenCV library not found. Using OpenCV Manager for initialization");
        OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_0_0, this, mLoaderCallback);
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV library found inside package. Using it!");


        mLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);

    }
}


private static Bitmap makeBlackTransparent(Bitmap image) {
    // convert image to matrix
    Mat src = new Mat(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC4);
    Utils.bitmapToMat(image, src);

    // init new matrices
    Mat dst = new Mat(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC4);
    Mat tmp = new Mat(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC4);
    Mat alpha = new Mat(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC4);

    // convert image to grayscale
    Imgproc.cvtColor(src, tmp, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    // threshold the image to create alpha channel with complete transparency in black background region and zero transparency in foreground object region.
    Imgproc.threshold(tmp, alpha, 100, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);

    // split the original image into three single channel.
    List<Mat> rgb = new ArrayList<Mat>(3);
    Core.split(src, rgb);

    // Create the final result by merging three single channel and alpha(BGRA order)
    List<Mat> rgba = new ArrayList<Mat>(4);
    rgba.add(rgb.get(0));
    rgba.add(rgb.get(1));
    rgba.add(rgb.get(2));
    rgba.add(alpha);
    Core.merge(rgba, dst);

    // convert matrix to output bitmap
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Utils.matToBitmap(dst, output);
    return output;
}

public void debugger(String s){
    Log.v("", "########### " + s);
}
```

}

Comment: You can run as many tasks on as many threads as you like. Be aware that up to a certain point, performance doesn't get better by running more threads. Also, you don't get more cpu cycles by running more threads. The primary advantage of running multiple threads is that one task doesn't have to wait for another. Multi threading makes more efficient use of cycles, it doesn't create more cycles :-)

Comment: could you illustrate using my code how I can at least run 2 threads?

Comment: I want both threads to work on one task, afterwards a single output to be produced, how possible is that?

Comment: if `BackgroundRemover` consists of multiple sub tasks, or a task that is repeated on a number of objects, you'd have to add the code to split the work among multiple threads.